# How to close a bootstrap modal using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 5 modal that I am trying to close from typescript. When I call the function to close it. I get an error that saying undfined when the dismiss function
is called.

```
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons,NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalSizes } from 'src/app/core/utilities/modal-sizes';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
declare var window: any;

export class UploadComponent {
 
 @ViewChild("spinnerLoaderModal") content;
  loading = false;
  spinnerDuration = 2000;
  closeResult: string;
  //modalReference: NgbModalRef;
  modalReference: NgbModalRef;
 
 constructor(
   private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
   private modalService: NgbModal,){}


   //this.modalService.open(this.content, ModalSizes.lg);
   
 open(content){
    this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content);
    this.modalReference.result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed `;
    });
    //this.modalReference.close();
    }

 public closeSpinnerModal()
 {

  this.modalReference.dismiss(); 
 }
 
 public onSubmit(event : MouseEvent) {
 this.isLoading = true;
   this.open(this.content)
   timer(this.spinnerDuration).subscribe(this.closeSpinnerModal)
 }

}
```

HTML

```
<ng-template #spinnerLoaderModal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
<div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" id="spinLoader" class="form-control">
       </div>
            <img src="../../../../assets/images/loaderBlue.gif" id="bg" alt="" style="width:30%; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;">
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I am not an Angular dev, so common sense question: Can you try changing the `timer(..).subscribe(this.closeSpinnerModal)` to `timer(..).subscribe( val =>this.closeSpinnerModal() )`? It may be that the method is executed right there when you call it the way you are doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use "flat arrow" in subscribe so, the scope will be the component

```
timer(1000).subscribe(()=>this.closeSpinnerModal())
```

NOTE1:there's no "let-d dismiss",

Inside the template you use

```
d.close('what ever') //to close and fall into "then(result)"
d.dismiss('what ever other')  //to close and fall into the (reason)
```

NOTE2: use

```
<img src="./assets/images/loaderBlue.gif">
//or
<img src="assets/images/loaderBlue.gif">
```

Rememeber, Angular create a directory, in this directory there are the index.html and a copy of your assets folder. It's form this folder where Angular look for the "images"